# I am using StormConfigs startOffsetTime as LatestTime but if storm is stopped then it is Losing data produced by the producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am using KafkaProducer to send data to storm and when configuring spout I have written below code.

```
spoutConfig.useStartOffsetTimeIfOffsetOutOfRange=true;
spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
```

but the problem is when i stop Storm Application(Dev environment) storm loses the data produced by the producer.
If i use:

```
spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.ErliestTime()
```

the data insertion starts from beginning.
Here I don't want any data loss if storm goes down still storm should take all data produced by the Producer.

Comment: Did you also happen to set ignoreZkOffsets to true?

Comment: Yes. I tried this option also

Comment: ignoreZkOffsets should be false, otherwise the spout will start over on redeploy/restart. I think you should post your spout config, and probably also the topology config, otherwise this is hard to debug.

Comment: But just FYI, you should not write new code using the `storm-kafka` module. Use the `storm-kafka-client` module instead. It only has support for starting at an offset in the Trident spout, but adding it to the regular spout would be pretty easy.

Comment: Code i am using :
        String topic = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_TOPIC);
        String zkRoot = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_ZKROOT);
        String groupId = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_CONSUMERGROUP);
        SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, zkRoot, groupId);
        spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
        spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing Can you please share any examples link which is using storm-kafka-client

Comment: Your setup looks fine. My guess would be that you are losing state in Zookeeper when you restart. Are you deploying to a proper Storm cluster with a persistent Zookeeper, or are you using e.g. LocalCluster or `storm dev-zookeeper`?

Comment: You can find both Trident and non-Trident examples for storm-kafka-client at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I am using LocalCluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalClusters clear their state every time you restart them (it essentially sets up a new Zookeeper cluster every time). They are for testing, not production workloads. This is why your spout is starting over.

Comment: Thanks .Now We are using storm-kafka-client  and it solved our issue.

Comment: Great. Just for context, the reason storm-kafka-client solves your issue is that storm-kafka stores state in Storm's Zookeeper instance, while storm-kafka-client stores it in your Kafka cluster. Happy it works for you.